# Angular-UI router, not refresh if coming from /modal routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-ui-modal

Is it possible to configure something globally so that every time a new route is entered it checks to see if the previous route began with /modal and if it did then don't refresh the controller, just remove the top modal from the stack?

I think I could probably achieve this with reloadOnSearch and using search parameters but then I'd have to set every route on the whole site to set reloadOnSearch because any route on the site could launch a modal so this is not desirable.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to put you state config here

Comment: Why are you going through the router if you just want to close the modal?

Comment: When I go from /state1 to /modal1 and then to /modal2 I want the URL to change and for the back button to go back to the previous state in the history. However, when you go back to /modal1 it should just close the second modal and then when you go back to /state1 it should close the first modal. None of this should reload state1 which has been sitting happily underneath the modals.

Comment: I could post my route config here but any solution needs to work with any generic route config. That's why I want to implement something to check whether a modal is being closed before the router kicks in. If the user has hit the back button then the URL should change back to what it was but the running of the controller should be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
     //codes
})
```

Comment: Yeah, that helps me run code when the state changes but how would you tell if the user had hit the back button, or if the history had updated because they were moving forward and opening a new state, and how would you cancel the refreshing of the new state without cancelling the URL change?

Comment: to stop refresh, do, `event.preventDefault = true`

Answer (score 0):

In simple angular route you could do this:

```
yourApp.run(function($rootScope, $location){
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, next, current) {
    // next: The next URL to which we are attempting to navigate
    // current: The URL that we are on before the route change

    if (current == 'modal1'){
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

In order to adjust this to `angular ui`, just change `$routeChangeStart` to the relevant one(`$stateChangeStart`, I think).

Comment: That's close, but the problem is that if the user moved from modal1 to a new state (but hasn't gone backwards) then the default action is prevented. This needs to work only when the user goes back, or the modal is dismissed.